# Yii2 kartik ajax delete stay on delete action

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

Iam using Kartik ajax forms to insert update and delete. after delete by ajax i redirect(in modal) to same create/submit form but when i submit after delete it again submits the delete button on save form button.
following is my code. of delete action.
Return from delete action to again create action.

```
    return [
            'title'=> "Add Partiexsds",
            'content'=>$this->renderAjax('create', [
                'model' => $model,'dataProvider1'=>$dataProvider1,'dataProvider2'=>$dataProvider2,
            ]),
            'footer'=> Html::button('Savea',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit",
                    'form'=>'caseparties-form','formaction'=>'cfms-hc/caseparties/create'])
                ."<br><br>".$this->renderAjax('_parties', [
                    'model' => $model,'dataProvider1'=>$dataProvider1,'dataProvider2'=>$dataProvider2,
                ])


        ];
```

The code which create delete button.
        function ($url, $model, $key) {

```
                 return \yii\bootstrap\Html::a('',
                   ['caseparties/delete','id'=>$model->ID] , [
                   'class'       => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash popup-modal',
                   'data-target' => '#ajaxCrudModal',
                   'role'=>'modal-remote',
                   'data-request-method'=>'post',
                   'id'          => 'popupModal',
                   'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                   'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to remove this entry?'
               ]);


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this.

```
 $this->registerJs(
'
 $("form").attr("action", "/cfms-hc/caseparties/create");

');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `form` action.

If you check your DOM with f12 tools in chrome or firefox and go to you `form`, before and after pressing the Delete button you'll se that Kartik ajax changes on the fly the url to the delete action.

The save button in the other hand does not have that logic, so the url to delete persist when and after you press the save button.

So, my suggestion, remove the default button save and use it as you use the delete button:

```
return \yii\bootstrap\Html::a('',
                   ['caseparties/save','id'=>$model->ID] , [
                   'class'       => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash popup-modal',
                   'data-target' => '#ajaxCrudModal',
                   'role'=>'modal-remote',
                   'data-request-method'=>'post',
                   'id'          => 'popupModal',

               ]);
```

So when you click it, it attacks de form and changes the action to the one that saves the data.